# PHP: is_int return wrong result

Tags: php

I am posting numeric value by a form and in php file use `var_dump(is_int($my_var));` but it return `bool(false)` though i am posting **1** and if I use `var_dump(is_int(1));` it is fine and return `bool(true)`
what is wrong....?

Comment: what does `var_dump($my_var);` return?

Comment: check $my_var type, if is_int($my_var) returns false, $my_var must be something else than an integer

Comment: if your variable `$my_var` contains input from a form (as your first sentence suggests), it will contain data of type string - php doesn't do any automatic conversion of form data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables transmitted by a POST request are strings, so you're calling `is_int()` on a string which returns false.

You may use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) or [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) instead or simply cast your variable to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
// First check if it's a numeric value as either a string or number
    if(is_numeric($int) === TRUE){

        // It's a number, but it has to be an integer
        if((int)$int == $int){

            return TRUE;

        // It's a number, but not an integer, so we fail
        }else{

            return FALSE;
        }

    // Not a number
    }else{

        return FALSE;
    }
```

Also, instead of getting the variable as

```
$my_var = $_POST["value"];
```

try this instead to see if the value is really passed.

```
$my_var = $_REQUEST["value"];
```

Comment: You can reduce your whole code snippet to `return (int)$int == $int;`